# Blank entries added to Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently learning EmberJS as I feel single page apps using a JS framework and consuming a backend API are the way things are going to be moving. I've recently learned Laravel without any particular problem, but I'm finding Ember remarkably difficult.

Most of my issues I've worked through, but I'm having one that I don't even know how to debug.

Essentially, my interface displays a list of clients. Clicking on a name goes to that client. All of this is connected to a PHP/Laravel based API, which is working entirely fine and in the right format. Data is not the problem here.

That said, I should point out that my data does not have an "id" strictly, but connects using something more like a guid: 912ec803b2 instead of 231. The API is built to handle that, and it's a requirement. It also means there is no "id" in the data, but there is a "hash" which may potentially be confusing ember in some way?

This basic functionality just doesn't seem to work correctly. When a user clicks the Client link, it does navigate to the client. But it's adding a blank row to the clients list page, then going to the client page. Returning to the clients page shows the extra blank row, and the same thing will recur if clicked again.

Checking the Ember inspector in Chrome shows the data collection increasing, with blank data being added. I'm not sure why.

I've posted the code here. This should be all that's necessary. Is this behaviour a common trap for young players, of have I done something unusual?

Apologies for the length, just didn't want to omit something relevant.

```
// app.js

App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('clients', function() {
        this.route('new');

    });
    this.resource('client', { path: 'clients/:client_hash' }, function(){

    });


});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    url: 'http://myclientinfo'
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});

App.Client = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    hash: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ClientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('client');
  }
});

App.ClientIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('client', params.client_hash);
  }
});


// templates

    <script type="text/x-handlebars">

    <div class="container">

      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li>{{#link-to 'clients'}}Clients{{/link-to}}</li>
      </ul>


      {{outlet }}

      </div>
    </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="client">
  client outer
  {{outlet}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="clients">
  client outer
  {{outlet}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="client/index">
  client index
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="clients/index">

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <h1>All Clients</h1>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  {{#link-to 'clients.new' class="btn btn-info add-btn"}}
  <i class="fa fa-plus"> Add new client</i>
  {{/link-to}}
  </div></div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">

    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

      {{#each item in model}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{#link-to 'client' item.hash}}{{item.name}}{{/link-to}}</td>

      </tr>
      {{/each}}

      </tbody>
    </table>


    </div>
    </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: This sounds like your adapter is not serializing the data properly.  Can you post the network response you get when you navigate to a `Client` from the `Clients` route?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to, but I'm assuming something like Chrome dev tools' network tab? If there's an ember-specific tool let me know.

All it says in that is GET /api/clients - 200 OK

Worth noting that it never says GET /api/clients/2/... Not sure if that means anything.

Comment: Additionally, I have modified both the API and the Ember to make it no longer use the hash mentioned above. I'm now using a standard integer ID to simplify any break with convention that might be causing my problems. It hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Yes, the network response is what I'm talking about-  if you're using the chrome network tab, click on the request, then the tab to the right that says "response" or "preview".  And yes, there is an Ember extension for the chrome debugger: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just following this up since I've sorta kinda fixed it.

```
this.resource('client', { path: 'clients/:client_hash' }, function(){
```

This line did more than I thought. I thought it was more of a defining placeholder, like in Laravel.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
```

The name used, whether it's {id} or {hash} or {poopypants} doesn't matter because it's being defined and used at that time.

I changed it to this:

```
this.resource('client', { path: 'clients/:client_id' }, function(){
```

That lets the default link-to helpers work, rather than simply getting "undefined" like they were for everything else I tried. The name of that segment is actually meaningful, it is used to derive the actual values for the segment.

With this done I was able to refactor the loop code slightly, fixing the helper.

```
{{#each item in model}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{#link-to 'client' item}}{{item.name}}{{/link-to}}</td>
```

This could also be refactored down more.

```
{{#each}}
<tr>
    <td>{{#link-to 'client' this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</td>
```

Note that `{{#link-to 'client' this}}` works, while `{{#link-to 'client' this.id}}` mostly works, but gets the bug stated in the OP. A bug that I believe has taken me three DAYS to fix.